# Jquery and javascript not showing up in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I was working on a jquery clicker game when I added a line of code and suddenly all of my javascript stopped showing up in my html, however I looked through all of my code and it seems all correct.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var credits = 0;
var creditstarter = 1;
var hanzounlocked = 0;
var hanzocost = 100;
var numsonicarrow = 0;
var sonicarrowcost = 50;
var numscatterarrow = 0;
var scatterarrowcost = 280;
var numdragonstrike = 0;
var dragonstrikecost = 1000;
var junkratunlocked = 0;
var junkratcost = 4500;
var numtrap = 0;
var trapcost = 5000;
var numconcussionmine = 0;
var concussionminecost = 8000;
var numriptire = 0;
var riptirecost = 16000;
var tracerunlocked = 0;
var tracercost = 50000;
var numblink = 0;
var blinkcost = 15000;
var numrecall = 0;
var recallcost = 40000;
var numpulsebomb = 0;
var pulsebombcost = 100000;
var dvaunlocked = 0;
var dvacost = 400000;
var numdefencematrix = 0;
var defencematrixcost = 100000;
var nummicromissiles = 0;
var micromissilescost = 185000;
var numselfdestruct = 0;
var selfdestructcost = 900000;

$('#openlootbox').on('click', function () {
 credits = credits + creditstarter + numdragonstrike + numriptire + 
numpulsebomb + numselfdestruct;
});

$('#hanzo').on('click', function (){
  hanzounlocked++;

  credits -= hanzocost;

}); 
$('#sonicarrow').on('click', function () {
   numsonicarrow++;
   credits -= sonicarrowcost;
   sonicarrowcost = Math.ceil(sonicarrowcost * 1.2);
});


$('#scatterarrow').on('click', function () {
   numscatterarrow++;
   credits -= scatterarrowcost;
   scatterarrowcost = Math.ceil(scatterarrowcost * 1.2);
});

$('#dragonstrike').on('click', function() {
  numdragonstrike++;
credits -= dragonstrikecost;
dragonstrikecost = Math.ceil(dragonstrikecost * 1.2);
});

window.setInterval(function () {

  if(hanzounlocked > 0){
 $('#hanzo').prop('disabled', true);
 $('#scatterarrow').prop('disabled', false);
 $('#sonicarrow').prop('disabled', false);
 $('#dragonstrike').prop('disabled', false);
}

    if(hanzounlocked === 0){
 $('#sonicarrow').prop('disabled', true);
 $('#hanzo').prop('disabled', false);
 $('#dragonstrike').prop('disabled', true);
 $('#scatterarrow').prop('disabled', true);
}

if(credits < hanzocost){
 $('#hanzo').prop('disabled', true);
}

if(credits < scatterarrowcost){
 $('#scatterarrow').prop('disabled', true);
}

if(credits < sonicarrowcost){
 $('#sonicarrow').prop('disabled', true);
}

if(credits < dragonstrikecost){
 $('#dragonstrike').prop('disabled', true);
}

//Update the text showing how many coins you have and round down
$('#credits').text(Math.floor(credits));



credits += (numsonicarrow * 1 / 100);

 //scatterarrow adds 5 per second (5/100 every 10ms)
credits += (numscatterarrow * 5 / 100);
credits += (numconcussionmine * 15 / 100); 
credits += (numtrap * 50 / 100);
credits += (numblink * 150 / 100);
credits += (numrecall * 390 / 100);
credits += (numdefencematrix * 1170 / 100);
credits += (nummicriomissiles * 3120 / 100);


});
});
```

And now the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>OW Clicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="clicker.css" type="text/css">
  <script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="newgame.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Luckiest+Guy" />
 <style type="text/css">
  </style>

<body>

  <button id="openlootbox"></button>
  <button id="hanzo"></button>
  <button id="sonicarrow"></button>
  <button id="scatterarrow"></button>
  <button id="dragonstrike"></button>

 </body>
</html>
```

I know that I may have formatted this question wrong, but I truly do not understand why my buttons are not showing up with my .text functions. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- `nummicromissiles` is misspelled as `nummicriomissiles`. You can open your browser dev tools by pressing f12 to see any errors in the console.
- There is no element with an id of `credits` so `$('#credits').text(Math.floor(credits));` does not do anything.